# Add to car button hides after clicked

Tags: php, css, woocommerce

In single product page using Flatsome theme

When the user click on the "add to cart" button the product is added to the cart but then the button is hidden.

Causing the customer to be unabled to add the product again

I need a function to make the button stay visible

Comment: a test link to view  https://www.borsawya.com/product/16/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The display:none property is added to the element when clicked.

Just remove this function from your css file. After that, it can't be hidden anymore.

```
.added {
    display: none;
}
```